# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' has no attribute 'Rescaling'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I try:

```
normalization_layer = layers.Rescaling(1./255)
```

error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' has no attribute 'Rescaling'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You might be using a wrong version of tf.

Comment: which tensorflow version are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, I used a wrong version of tf. Rescaling in tf v2.70, i used v2.60.

A preprocessing layer which rescales input values to a new range.
Inherits From: Layer, Module

```
tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(
    scale, offset=0.0, **kwargs
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error in v2.5.0

```
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling()
```

I guess this is the "old" way to use this layer

Comment: same for `Resizing` and `RandomCrop` layers.